# IE jerky when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This works well in all browsers except IE.
How do I fix this? when I scroll in IE it is very jerky.

http://jsfiddle.net/cc48t/

```
//js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#scroller').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: It was jerky in IE10 for me.

Comment: I can't seem to open any of these fiddles in IE8... The formatting of the fiddle page is all messed up. Does anyone know why? (There is a handful of JS errors from fiddle, I think)

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't work in IE8 as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cc48t/982/)):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#scroller').addClass("top");
    }
    else {
        $('#scroller').removeClass("top");
    }
});
```

And CSS:

```
#scroller {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #CCC;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#scroller.top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

EDIT: I added the set `width` and `margin` to `#scroller`, and set `left: 50%` and `margin-left: -250px;` (Half of the set width) to the .top class

Comment: look s great  on more think if its fixed  margin: o auto wont put the div in the middle of the screen  do you have a solution for that? thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer and the fiddle to reflect a fixed-width div centered in the screen. You can do the same thing with a % based width.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this too ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cc48t/981/))

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        //$('#scroller').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
        $('#scroller').css('top', '0px');
        $('#scroller').css('position', 'fixed');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#scroller').css('top', '100px');
        $('#scroller').css('position', 'absolute');
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Essentially the same thing as mine, but mine keeps CSS in the CSS